# PHP - DatePicker/String conversion to SQL Date

Tags: php, datepicker, date-conversion

I have a DatePicker that gives me a value like this "10-Nov-2016". I want to convert this date into a SQL Date such as "2016/10/22".

What would be the best way to do this?

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or procedural version [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php).

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [date()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.strtotime.php) function

```
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime('15-Feb-2009'));
```

[demo](https://eval.in/671587)